# How to download Windows IoT on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: download, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, windowsiot

I am trying to download the windows preview release for Raspberry Pi 3, I am unable to figure out how I can find a download link.

What I have tried

1. Signed up for insider @ "[Windows Insider](https://insider.windows.com/)"
2. Trying to follow this tutorial [IoT on Raspberry pi 3](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/win10/getstarted/setupyourdevicemanually)
3. But when ever I hit **Get Windows 10 IoT Core Insider Preview** I always see this page [Windows IoT download](https://auth.windowsondevices.com/InsiderSignupRedirect?retryUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fauth.windowsondevices.com%2F)

I am trying to figuring it out for last couple of hours, why it is always saying to signup as Insider however I am already an insider?

any help is appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Are you able to make it to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsiot?

Comment: Hello @Jackie Thanks for the link, actually the first day I signed up for WIndows Insider this link was not working, but second day it starts working. Probably Microsoft takes some time to setup an insider account behind the scene. Thanks although!

Comment: Glad  it works now!

Answer (score 1):

Closing this question.

Reason:

The link provided was not working the first day I signed up for Microsoft insider, but same link worked the next day, Probably Microsoft takes some time to setup an insider account behind the scene.

Answer (score 0):

Use the IoT Dashboard app.

Get it from here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/win10/GetStarted/rpi3/sdcard/insider/GetStartedStep1.htm

This guides you through creating the SD card and connecting to the device once it's running.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit late for the answer but it might be useful to somebody looking to install Windows IoT on Raspberry Pi.I agree that Windows IoT dashboard and Windows device portal are quiet useful for managing devices running windows IoT from single place.This is one of the most useful features of Windows IoT.So I would suggest fir install IoT dashboard and then install Windows IoT from there.

Once IoT dashboard is installed you can perform tasks such as installing Windows IoT on SD card.It also provides you access to device portal and remote client.You can debig your application using these.You can install dashbiard from here https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/Downloads .
Following might be useful  [Install Windows IoT on Raspberry Pi](http://www.codecompiled.com/iot/installing-windows-10-iot-core-on-raspberry-pi/)